# CPU-Only OpenCL Environment on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, opencl

Is there any way to install an OpenCL runtime on Ubuntu 16.04 running in a VM? I've tried AMD APP and Intel CPU-Only runtime, but none can be detected by clinfo. I've been using libpocl1 on 15.10, and the package also exists in Ubuntu 16.10. However, this package neither exists in 16.04, nor the 15.10 version deb file can be installed and used.

So, any way I can run an OpenCL program in a VM on 16.04? If not, I will have to go back to 15.10. Keep in mind that I'm doing cross compiling (develop and test on Linux since I need Valgrind and autotools, and release for Windows), so the latest version of mingw-w64 is also crucial, and that's one major driving force for me to try 16.04.